# How can I run the Total Phase Aardvark python API on linux without being root?

Tags: python, linux, i2c, udev

I have the [Total Phase Aardvark](http://www.totalphase.com/products/aardvark-i2cspi/) which I am using to script I2C commands to a piece of hardware from linux.  I am using the python API [aardvark_py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aardvark-py/5.15.2), but when I try to list devices I get an error -2:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: from aardvark_py import *
In [2]: aa_find_devices(1)
Out[2]: (-2, array('H'))
```

If I run as root using sudo then I am able to connect to my device

```
$ sudo ipython
In [1]: from aardvark_py import *
In [2]: aa_find_devices(1)
Out[2]: (1, array('H', [0]))
```

I have installed the appropriate udev rules from total phase per their [support article](http://www.totalphase.com/support/articles/200468316).  And using their GUI application can discover and talk to the aardvark without being superuser.

I've verified that the udev rules are working because the device is world read/writeable:

```
$ lsusb | grep 0403
Bus 001 Device 043: ID 0403:e0d0 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd Total Phase Aardvark I2C/SPI Host Adapter
$ ll /dev/bus/usb/001/043 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 189, 42 Oct 20 15:20 /dev/bus/usb/001/043
```

Any ideas on how I can run my aardvark_py script without being superuser?